# How to pass secret from credentials in jenkins file with '=$' sign in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cypress

I have a credential that is saved in jenkins file with the value 'V%9I!%Lw(w-_1,W=$Za%rh!{1' which needs to be passed to my cypress test execution as shown below in jenkinsfile.

```
 stage('StageName') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([
          .........
          string(credentialsId: 'Client_Secret_D4_Backoffice_Admin', variable: 'Client_Secret_D4_Backoffice_Admin')

        ]) {
            sh """
                            
              npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@release',clientId=.......,backofficeAdminPassword='\${Client_Secret_D4_Backoffice_Admin}' --browser chrome --config-file D4-CDS-stage-cypress.config.ts

                        """
            
        } // End of sh
        } // End of steps
```

I notice that the value being considered is V%9I!%Lw(w-_1,W=%rh!{1 which is missing the '$Za' characters. How do I fix this? Thanks

Tried using export option to store the variable in a different variable and use that instead. But no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Java string instead of G-String, which do interpolation before pass string to shell, and then shell try to interpolate $Za... variable.
Replace `"""<your code>"""` with `'''<your code>'''`

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the problem is that you're scaping '$' inside gstring.

I try with you credential value with the following code, and the password is showed as expected:

```
node {
  tokenVar = null
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    tokenVar = """${TOKEN}"""
  }
  
  echo """$tokenVar"""
  
}
```

I assigned a var outside the `withCredentials` in order to see the password, because inside the closure there is a protection which masks it.

The output shows the expected password:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials (hide)
Masking supported pattern matches of $TOKEN
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] echo
V%9I!%Lw(w-_1,W=$Za%rh!{1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Therefore try using `'${Client_Secret_D4_Backoffice_Admin}'` instead of `'\${Client_Secret_D4_Backoffice_Admin}'`.